# Centered prime squared in a triple of primes which divides the sum of the three primes squared

Tags: number-theory

Let be $p_k$, $p_{k+2}$ and $p_{k+4}$ three primes

Now consider this example:

$5^2$ divides $2^2+5^2+11^2$.

I ask for for primes $(p_{k+2})^2$ dividing the following sum:

$(p_k)^2$+$(p_{k+2})^2$+$(p_{k+4})^2$.

Are there infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Have you heard of the n^2 + 1 conjecture (Landau's conjecture) and the Twin Prime conjecture? These are both hard conjectures that take on a sort of similar form, at present I don't see an obvious way to rule out that there are infinitely many solutions to this...

Comment: It seems that there is only the solution $2/5/11$. Upto $10^8$, there is no other solution.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking this question? [Additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/646141), such as your own thoughts, background, or the origin of this question would likely help responders provide more useful answer.

Comment: Still no second solution upto $10^9$

Comment: Do they have to be primes of position $k, k+2$ and $k+4$? Or can they be just primes that where we are squaring the middle one and checking it is it a factor?

Comment: @theREALyumdub I apologize for a mistake I made in my answer. I used the limit of the infimum of the prime gaps, which doesn't give an upper bound. Instead, as discussed in Wikipedia's section on Upper Bounds of [Prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds), the best proven result is that $g_n \lt p_n^{0.525}$. However, this is insufficient to rule out having a divisor of $p_{k+2}^2$. Thus, I agree with your earlier comment that there is no apparent way to rule out having infinite solutions. Since I don't know how to properly fix what I wrote, I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @homunculus As I wrote in my comment to theREALyumdub, my answer is incorrect & I don't see any way to fix it, so I've deleted it. I'm sorry for making the mistake initially & not realizing it up until now.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ok, I'm not very good with some of the number theory anyways so I wondered about using an infimum instead of supremum but didn't comment. I think you were on a good track with using gaps though, you may as well answer partially with that.

Comment: @theREALyumdub Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, with just what's been proven so far vs. any unproven conjectures, using prime gaps just shows, at the most, that any solutions will be quite "rare", but doesn't prevent possibly having an infinite # of them. I can't really say much more than what Peter's answer already states re: using prime gaps, so IMO there's not much point in my providing another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, the three primes in the triple are $\ p-a\ $ , $\ p\ $ and $\ p+b\ $ with positive integers $a,b$. Then, for a solution it is necessary that $\ p\mid a^2+b^2 $ , in particular $\ p\le a^2+b^2\ $

For a prime $\ q=p_k\ $ denote $\ r=p_{k+2}\ $

If $\ d:=r-q\ $ satisfies $\ 2d^2<q\ $ for $q>3121$ , then a prime $q>3121$ cannot be the middle prime. This seems to be the case, but it is probably hard to prove.